# Which domain or IP I should whitelist in firewall for Android FCM?

Tags: android, networking, push-notification, port, firewall

Good day,

For the MFP Push notification in Android FCM, I am quite confuse which ip address or domain I need to ask network team to whitelist.

I am referring the following 2 articles:

```
 1. https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#scope-mapping
 2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
```

So what I have to tell network team, is it to ask them to whitelist all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google’s ASN of 15169 ?

How about the `fcm.googleapis.com` that mention in first article? Is it need to whitelist as well? Means network team need to whitelist the following 2 thing:

```
 1. `fcm.googleapis.com`, with port 443 (no need 5228, 5229 and 5230?)
 2. all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google’s ASN of 15169 (with port 5228, 5229, 5230, no need 443?)
```

Am I correct?

Actually which url is fire from MFP to FCM? is the `fcm.googleapis.com`? Or to a domain, which the ip will keep changing?

Kindly advise. 
Explain in layman term is welcome, as I am new on this, and no knowledge on networking.

Answer (score 0):

fcm.googleapis.com is for App Server (Server side) to push / send / trigger notification to FCM, whereas whitelisted IPs are for mobile devices (Client side).